# Error while copying a column of one dataframe to another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, webhdfs

I am trying to replace the column "X" of dataframe *df1* by column "X" of dataframe *df2*. I use the below code:

```
df1$X <- df2$X
```

The above line of code works well in RStudio environment. However, when I run the R script on my Ubuntu VM from command line and load the dataframes by CSV files fetched from hdfs, the above line of code gives the below error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "X", value = c(3.688879454,  :
>   replacement has 1464 rows, data has 161

I tried different indexing methods and solutions from google but could not solve it. I am guessing the issue might be because column "X" of df1 has some missing values. I cannot find a solution to fix this.

Here is the code prior to the line of code in question:

```
require(rhdfs)
hdfs.init()
f = hdfs.file(file_input,"r",buffersize=104857600)
m = hdfs.read(f)
con = rawToChar(m)
Df1 = read.table(textConnection(con), sep = ",",header=TRUE, fill = TRUE)

f1 = hdfs.file(file_input1,"r",buffersize=104857600)
m1 = hdfs.read(f1)
con1 = rawToChar(m1)
df2 = read.table(textConnection(con1), sep = ",",header=TRUE, fill = TRUE)

Df1$X <- df2$X
```

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? It seems that some operation on df2 is changing its size before you try to replace in df1

Comment: @csgroen: I have updated the question with additional code. Thanks.

Comment: Can't install rhdfs (not available for R 3.4.1). Can you dput(Df1) and dput(Df2) and post the results?

Comment: The outputs are the data from the csv files. Since the csv files are large, it is not possible to post the results here. dput basically lists all the rows and columns from both the file inputs.

Comment: Well... what's dim(Df1) and dim(df2)?

Comment: Df1  - 161 80
df2   -  1464 6
Now, I notice that the file is not completely fetched from the hdfs. Probably some streaming error. Silly of me to not have checked this before posting.